# Can I add onclick listener to embedded pdf in html?

Tags: jquery, html, pdf

I have embedded pdf in jsp page:

```
<object type="${image.mimeType}" data="${imageDataUrl}&.pdf#view=FitH" >
   Download the <a href="${imageDataUrl}&.pdf">report</a>.
</object>
```

From firebug, I can see the print button element in pdf tool bar:

```
<button data-l10n-id="print" id="print" title="Print" class="toolbarButton print">
   <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
</button>
```

Is there any way to add onclick to this button? I've tried the following jquery but didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#print").click(function(){
        alert("print");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Arun `$(document).ready` is the older equivalent of your last suggestion.

Comment: This looks fine. The problem may be elsewhere in your page. Could you have two elements with the same id maybe?

Comment: Not in IFrame. I added in function but doesn't work.